# Horizontally Scrolling Containers Webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a mobile-oriented website with three cards that will be horizontally scrollable and take up just one (100% of a) page of the user's device (no vertical scroll). The first card will have text, the second will have a weather widget, and the third a google maps widget. Right now with the code, I found on CSS Tricks it's not working. Below is my code and the result.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  ;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.card {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 66px 0px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 66px 0px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 66px 0px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.75);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card-body {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.scrolling-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-color: ivory;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
}


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline|Poppins:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Document</h1>
  <h2>Wednesday January 16th, 2019</h2>

  <div class="scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Today's Schedule</h3>
        <p>
          <b>9:00 AM:</b> Go to the Park
          <b>12:00 PM:</b> Go to the Park
          <b>3:00 PM:</b> Go to the Park
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Weather</h3>
        <a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/en/31d7735d21/jerusalem/?unit=us" data-label_1="JERUSALEM" data-label_2="WEATHER" data-font="Verdana" data-icons="Climacons" data-mode="Forecast" data-days="3" data-theme="pure">JERUSALEM WEATHER</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Map</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }
    }(document, 'script', 'weatherwidget-io-js');
  </script>

</html>
```

**Results:**

[Image Result from a computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ovAm.png)

[Result on Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl0mh.png)

Comment: Hi Max! Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you add the CSS Tricks that you followed? Also, you might want to experiment with `width: 100vw`, meaning the container will be 100% of the device's width. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I hope it is what you want:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  ;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.card {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 66px 0px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 66px 0px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 66px 0px rgba(74, 74, 74, 0.75);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: left;
  height: 300px;

}

.card-body  p b{
  display: block;
}


.card-body {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.scrolling-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-color: ivory;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline|Poppins:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Document</h1>
  <h2>Wednesday January 16th, 2019</h2>

  <div class="scrolling-wrapper">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Today's Schedule</h3>
        <p>
          <b>9:00 AM:</b> Go to the Park
          <b>12:00 PM:</b> Go to the Park
          <b>3:00 PM:</b> Go to the Park
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Weather</h3>
        <a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/en/31d7735d21/jerusalem/?unit=us" data-label_1="JERUSALEM" data-label_2="WEATHER" data-font="Verdana" data-icons="Climacons" data-mode="Forecast" data-days="3" data-theme="pure">JERUSALEM WEATHER</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Map</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    ! function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }
    }(document, 'script', 'weatherwidget-io-js');
  </script>

</html>
```

I removed the `display: inline-block` from `.card` wich caused the `divs` to be displayed next to each other instead of below each other.

**Update**:
I added the selector for the `b`s within the card body, so the time and description of the schedule are displayed each in one seperate line.